# Mudar cor do layout

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css3, codeigniter

Eu queria criar uma função para mudar as cores do layout do site que estão desenvolvendo, esse site é feito em CodeIgniter, CSS3 e um pouco de Javascript puro, eu dei uma pesquisada na internet e não encontrei muita coisa, mas pelo pouco conhecimento que tenho acredito que seja em JS esse tipo de modificação. A função ficaria no Dashboard e o usuário poderá mudar as cores assim que desejar, cores já pré definidas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exatamente, você pode usar JS, utilizando o atributo `.style` para alterar o CSS de uma `div`. Veja esse exemplo

```css
#quadrado {
    background: #000;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id='quadrado'></div>

<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('quadrado').style.background = 'blue'">Deixar azul!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('quadrado').style.background = 'red'">Deixar vermelho!</button>
<button type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('quadrado').style.background = 'green'">Deixar verde!</button>
```

Nele, ao clicarmos em algum dos botões, selecionamos através do ID o quadrado e alteramos a propriedade `background`, inserindo a cor que desejamos. Essa é só uma base para que você possa customizar de acordo com suas necessidades.

Comment: +1 ! Muito Obrigada!  Me deu uma direção (;